How to get current dash ag-grid settings in call back
The problem is, I have a group data, which can be expanded on dash tab. I want to keep the row/column status, order, filter all the same when I left the tab. I use dcc.Store to save the settings from call back and then get them back when tab is back. However, the row status, order, expansion/collapse status seems has no property in dash ag grid.
Specificly, I would like to get the current expanding node and load it out when refresh/switch tab.
I believe this is the solution but how to do it in python
https://ag-grid.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016031851-Saving-Restoring-expanded-group-node-state-in-the-local-storage
my default dash grid option:
dashGridOptions = {
    "rowSelection": "multiple",
    "suppressAggFuncInHeader": True,
    "animateRows": False, "sideBar": sideBar, 'groupDefaultExpanded': 1, "autoGroupColumnDef": {
        "headerName": "",
        "minWidth": 300,
    }

}

my default column def:
[{"field": x, "rowGroup": True, "hide": True, "pivot": True,
                                "suppressColumnsToolPanel": True} for x in underlying_risk_header] + [
                                  {"field": x, "sortable": True, "filter": True, "aggFunc": "sum",
                                   "cellStyle": {
                                       "function": "params.value > 0 ? {'color': 'green'} : {'color': 'red'}"
                                   }, "valueFormatter": {"function": "d3.format(',.0f')(params.value)"}} for
                                  x in
                                  underlying_risk_cols]

The callback to save the filter mode, I would like to save the order status, expand/collapse status as well.
@callback(
    Output('iday-pv_table_setting', 'data', allow_duplicate=True),
    Input('iday-pivot-table-pv', 'columnDefs'),
    Input('iday-pivot-table-pv', 'columnState'),
    Input('iday-pivot-table-pv', 'filterModel'),
    Input('iday-pivot-table-pv', 'dashGridOptions'),
    Input('iday-pivot-table-pv', 'defaultColDef'), prevent_initial_call=True
)
def save_pv_table_state(columnDefs, columnState, filterModel, dashGridOptions, defaultColDef):
    state = {
        'columnDefs': columnDefs,
        'columnState': columnState,
        'filterModel': filterModel,
        'dashGridOptions': dashGridOptions,
        'defaultColDef': defaultColDef,
    }
    return json.dumps(state)

